# Match .htm or .html extensions with python RE

Tags: python, html, regex, file, expression

As mentioned in the title, I need to match an *.htm* or *.html* file extension in Python.
I tried to use the RE module found in the standard library, but I can't find the right pattern.
I tested several patterns and, the patterns that seem more correct (for me) but have not worked are as follows:

```
re.search("\.(htm|html)",file)
re.search("\.htm(l)",file)
re.search("\.htm(l?)",file)
re.search("\.htm(l*?)",file)
re.search("\.htm(l+?)",file)
```

and others variants, but none works.
The problem is that, these patterns recognized file extensions like *.html* or similar and, I do not want them (only htm and html).

Can someone help me to find the right pattern?
thank you all

Comment: You need to match a file extension on a url or a local file ?

Comment: @Pedro they are on my pc.

Comment: You just need to check if the file extension match or you need to capture the matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `re.search('\.html?$', file)`. Parentheses are for creating capture groups, which you do not want to do here.

I'll also mention a more complicated, alternate solution because you seemed to be trying to do something like this: `re.search('\.(?:(?:html)|(?:htm))$', file)`. This will accomplish the same thing as the above RegEx, but is much longer and more complicated.

Finally, if you also want to get the name of the file, then do `re.search('^.*?\.html?$', file)`.

Comment: And if the file-name is `test.htmlimage.jpg` ? better put `$` at the regex end.

Comment: @pzp not work correctly. For expample it match .htmk files too.

Comment: @PedroLobito Good catch. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a regex in this case, use [endswith()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) instead, i.e.:

```
if filePath.lower().endswith(('.html', '.htm')):
```